# Auto fit(scale) TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

Нашел пару решений в сети по типу [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)

Но проблема в том, что перенос текста на следующую строку осуществляется самостоятельно(рандомно) и символ `\n` ни как не воспринимается. Если для каждой строки создавать отдельно TextView то у каждой строки получается разный размер шрифта в зависимости от длиины. Тоесть если я захочу вывести стих то в каждой строчке будет разный размер шрифта в зависимости от длинны строчки. Есть еще спосмобы? Может можно сделать auto scale всему layout в котором наодятся строки? Я не нашел способа :(. И кстати ни одо решение не работает с русскими символами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятна проблема. Может вас устроит `wrap_content` для ширины и высоты и перенос строк тегом `<br>` и установка текста через `Html.fromHtml()`?

Comment: Собственно у меня два `Layout`. В одном телефоны в другом информация от пользователя. Как видите все `TextView` имеют разный шрифт и смотрится это ужасно. Шрифт меняется так чтобы весь текст влез в строку.

Comment: В голову приходит только какт-то во время работы app определить какая строчка имеет самый маленький шрифт и дать остальным такой  же размер...

Comment: И вас не устраивает обычное поведение, когда идёт перенос строк? А если вместо переноса строки текст в конце будет убран и заменён точками? Типа `длинный-длинный тек...`?

Comment: А если для номера вообще будет мало места? Как оно перенесет? Office: перенос 055- перенос- 111- перенос-02 перенос? Длинный тест с ... не подойдет. Надо чтобы отображалось все.

Comment: У меня динамический layout и надо чтобы все TV плясали под его длинну одинаково. А не по одиночку

Comment: Т.к. на телефонах вообще мало места, а ещё есть пользовательские размеры теста, устанавливаемые на уровне системы то, думаю, невозможно на всех экранах сделать нормально текст так, чтобы всем юзерам было удобно и красиво. Я бы решил проблему установив везде один размер шрифта, по одному `TextView` на одну строку-номер, сокращал бы длинный текст точками (это аттрибут `android:ellipsize`) и при нажатии на номер выводил бы его в отдельном диалоге.

Comment: Как вариант...Если ничего не получится попробую этот способ. Спасибо. Я так понял что с webview тоже выкрутиться не получится?

Comment: Насколько я знаю - да, не получится. Тем более, что оно ещё и прожорливое и лагать всё начнёт.

Answer (score 1):

`TextView` в `Android` немножко противоречивый. Если хотите форматировать текст как угодно - используйте `WebView`. Просто кормите отформатированную `String`/файл с текстом и наслаждаетесь результатом:

```
String data = ""<html>...</html>"";
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Вариант интерестный есть над чем подумать. А если webview динамически миняется. Сохранится ли в нем форматирование текста?